# i can't setState graphql queries on gatsby js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have tried to fetch data `onClick` with GraphQL but for some reason I can't `setState` multiple queries. It says (Loading Static query)

```
class Math extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: url,
      value2: texts[1],
      value3: queryOne,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Sidebar>
          <div
            className="post"
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({
                value: pablo,
                value2: texts[1],
               value3: queryTwo,
              })
            }
          >
            <img src={pablo} alt="pablo"/>
            <h3>1deg school</h3>
          </div>
          <div
            className="post"
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState({ value: clip, value2: texts[2], value3: queryOne })
            }
          >
            <img src={clip} alt="clip"/>
            <h3>2deg school</h3>
          </div>
        </Sidebar>
        <Content>
          <img src={this.state.value} alt="img"></img>
          <p>{this.state.value2}</p>
          <div className="posts">
            <StaticQuery
              query={queryOne}
              render={data => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
                      <Post
                        title={node.frontmatter.title}
                        path={node.frontmatter.path}
                        body={node.excerpt}
                        date={node.frontmatter.date}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </Content>
    )
  }
}
const queryOne = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            date
            path
          }
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
const queryTwo = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/001/" } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            titledatepath
          }
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
export default Math
```

I can switch only between images, and it shows this warning:

> We were unable to find the declaration of variable "value3", which you
>   passed as the "query" prop into the  declaration

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what exactly you are trying to do but you can't pass variables for static queries. They must be truly static and the queries passed directly into query attribute:

```
<StaticQuery query={graphql`query MyStaticQuery {...}`} />
```

This way they can be discovered, extracted and transformed into static json during develop/build.

Comment: yes i want to know how can i use setState in react to switch between queries .. on Click

Comment: First, you can't have more than one static query per file. That leaves you with using page queries where you can do multiple `allMarkdownRemark` requests using graphql aliases or passing the query results to page context on `createPages` API

Comment: Okey i will try passing the query results to page context ... Thank you so much bro !